# Does Aws Device Farm supports Appium automation in ruby?

Tags: appium, aws-device-farm

I see `AWS Device Farm` support for Calabash to run Ruby tests, meanwhile, unable find any documentation regarding `Appium Ruby` combination for WebApp automation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AWS Device Farm still provides only `server-side` way of executing tests, and its limited to Java/Python support in combination with Appium.

If you already have set of tests in Ruby, the best option is to look for device clouds with `client-side` execution (there are many of them today), then you won't be dependent in what language to code your tests, just set host/capabilities of cloud service.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reaching out. We do not support appium/Ruby combination on the public fleet as of today. We do have plans to support more frameworks on the public fleet in 2018.

However, we recently launched a Feature called Direct Device Access where customer tests runs on the client side. You can use Direct Device Access to run your appium/ruby tests on Device Farm. However Direct Device Feature is only available on private devices.

To know more about Direct Device Access and Private Devices, please see the links below
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/direct-device-access.html
https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/pricing/#privateDevices

Comment: Hi Anurag Goyal - how does one purchase Private Devices? We can't seem to find it in the UI.

Answer (score -1):

You could get a private device pool in device farm.  Then you could run any testing framework you want.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/10/amazon-device-farm-launches-direct-device-access-for-private-devices/